# Removing data from JSON list/arraylist/hashmap

Tags: android, json

i have 2 listview activities, the first listview has categories while the second has everything else (both reading JSON files)

what i am trying to do is to get the category from the first activity (one with categories) and then only display the objects in the JSON that have the same category
but i do not understand how to do this, i tried remove and i also tried if statements and etc
this is the latest code i am using to delete the parts of the arraylist which are not the same category

```
        for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
            if((contactList.get(i).get(TAG_CATEGORY)).toString().equals(title.toString())) {
            } else {
                contactList.remove(i);
            }                   
        }
```

but it doesnt seem to be working, i still get all the read data from the JSON

**Edit: it seems this code is only working for the first 2 objects in the JSON array**

Answer (score -1):

OK , I hope i understand you well , You will need to add to list view (activity one)
listener to get position of clicked one , and send send it AS Extras to Bundle , then in your Second activity , get the Category index or name , and make Loop on Other Objects to fetch which one related to That Category .

```
categoryListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // get Position or String of Category and start New Activity with Extras 
        }
    });
```

start activity like that

```
Intent i = new Intent(secondactivity.class,firstActivity.this);
i.putExtra("category", "science");
startActivity(i);
```

Second activity

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null)
{
    category = extras.getString("category");
    // fetch objects here and set adapter to view related items
}
```

Hope That Help

Comment: yes i did this and isnt exactly the problem i am getting
sorry for not being precise enough
i have 2 JSON files in my assets folder, one contains all the categories, the the other contains an array with many objects and these objects have a string in them that contain the category ("category": "Sleep",) 
now i would like to divide up these categories without creating various JSON files, and just use the 1 JSON file with all the objeccts
I would like to see what category is selected (already done) then display objects for that category (this is the problem)
Thanks

Comment: something like whats done here for the Second Level ListView http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/
but that one is for a url, while i have a json file in my assets folder

Comment: step #1 you can make JSON like That : {"category":["subCategory","subCategory", .. ],"category":["subCategory","subCategory", .. ]}

Comment: yes i thought of that but the JSON file is rather large and i am thinking it wud be bttr if there is some way to make it work without editing the json file much

that above code works for the first 2 JSON objects but not the rest :-/